# virtualenv cannot workon project

Tags: django, terminal, virtualenv, virtualbox

I have been trying to follow this particular guide on setting up a workon function where I am able to quickly switch from project to project within a virtualenv...
https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

I'm trying to re-organize my virtualenv into one particular folder ( I don't know if this is a smart or dumb idea...):

Structure:

```
-master_folder/                 #I'm currently in this folder
  -virtual_enviornments/
     -project1/
     -project2/
  -projects/
     -project1/
     -project2/
```

It so happens that I am stuck at the third step:

```
 $ pip install virtualenvwrapper
 $ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
 $ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh      #STUCK HERE
```

ERROR:  `-bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory`

I know the file does not exist within the directory, so am I supposed to create it some other way? I'm really confused... @.@

After running `which virtualenv`:

```
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv
```

Did I install my virtualenv incorrectly?
I did just do `pip install virtualenv`....

Thanks for all the help guys!

Comment: I realize this may come off as a dumb question but, did you have any problems with the installation of virtualenvwrapper? Is it possible that you _pip installed_ it with an environment activated?

Comment: @Mariano nope I installed it without activating the virtualenv

Comment: Try running which virtualenvwrapper.sh
instead of which virtualenv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont't think you have installed virtual environment correctly.

Please go through  this link

http://ayarshabeer.com/post/50973941605/install-multiple-django-version-using-virtualenvwrapper

Comment: stuck at  mkvirtualenv env1 can't move further.. :/

Comment: I think I got it working now... apparently my bash_profile was to be updated with the source from above... but something's been bugging me... why is everybody elses virtualenv .sh file inside the usr/local/bin folder but mine is in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` ??